# Running Redis on windows by compiling the source

Tags: windows, gcc, redis, mingw

If we have redis source code (written in C language) on github, then why just we don't compile it's source code and use it on windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Redis makes use of system calls that are only available on Linux and its ilk. Windows doesn't have these functions, so the code won't compile there.

Of course, Redis is open-source, so you are welcome to fork the code base and swap out those calls with their equivalents in Windows. And folks in the community have done this. This is where the various versions of Redis for Windows have come from. However, these version are not usually kept current with the latest version of Redis so they're not often used.

The best bet for running Linux on Windows is to use Windows Subsystem for Linux. I made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nFwPTHOMIY) explaining how to do this a couple of years back.

Comment: Why don't redis officially provide support for windows ?